# Replacing specific characters after a string match

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to replace specific characters  in numbers I'm extracting but I cannot figure out how to do so. 
Here "," is the float separator and (' or .) are thousands separators. I can match this way :

```
>>> myString = "I buy 456'123,45 then 45.654 then 123. I'm 30."
>>> re.findall(r"(?:\d+)(?:['|.]\d+)+(?:[,]\d+)?", myString)
["456'123,45", '45.654']
```

I want to replace in my string all thousands separator to get this :

```
>>> newString
"I buy 456123,45 then 45654 then 123. I'm 30."
```

I'm pretty sure I need to use groups and subgroups in order to replace what I want but I don't know how to deal with groups when "()+" is present, the length of the number can also be very long
(e.g : 123'456'789'123'456'789,123)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `re.sub` with

```
(?<=\d)['.](?=\d)
```

and replace with an empty string. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dLmnUH/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=\d)` - (positive lookbehind) a digit must appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `['.]` - a single quote or a dot
- `(?=\d)` - (positive lookahead) a digit must appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Python:

```
re.sub(r"(?<=\d)['.](?=\d)", "", myString)
```